# Need help displaying values from a DLL file

Tags: c#, dllimport

Here is the entire file. I'm trying to understand how to display the info from ODBAXIS. This code has a error code on line 130.

```
/*
 * 
 * */
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace SampleFOCAS2Projtest1
{

public partial class frmMacroVars : Form
{ 

    bool iConnected = false;
    short hndl;
    //ushort Flibhndl;

    //Read a macro variable
    [DllImport("fwlib32")]
    private static extern short cnc_rdmacro(short hndl, short number, short length, ref ODBM c);


    //[DllImport("FWLIB32")]
  // private static extern short cnc_absolute(short hndl, short number, short length, ref ODBAXIS c);


    /* read absolute axis position */
    [DllImport("FWLIB32.dll", EntryPoint = "cnc_absolute")]
    public static extern short cnc_absolute(short hndl,
    short a, short b, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] ODBAXIS c);

    // In the FOCAS2 Functions, long value types are equivalent to Int32 types in .NET
    // Write a macro variable
    [DllImport("fwlib32")]
    private static extern short cnc_wrmacro(short hndl, short number, short length, int mcr_val, short dec_val);

    //Once again, specify layout of the structure for communication with unmanaged DLL
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    public struct ODBM
    {
        public short datano;       /* custom macro variable number */
        public short dummy;        /* (not used) */
        public int mcr_val;        /* value of custom macro variable */
        public short dec_val;      /* number of places of decimals */

    }

    /* cnc_absolute:read absolute axis position */
    /* cnc_machine:read machine axis position */
    /* cnc_relative:read relative axis position */
    /* cnc_distance:read distance to go */
    /* cnc_skip:read skip position */
    /* cnc_srvdelay:read servo delay value */
    /* cnc_accdecdly:read acceleration/deceleration delay value */
    /* cnc_absolute2:read absolute axis position 2 */
    /* cnc_relative2:read relative axis position 2 */
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    public class ODBAXIS
    {
        public short dummy;  /* dummy */
        public short type;   /* axis number */
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public int[] data;      /* data value */




    }



    //Constructor
    public frmMacroVars(bool iConnect, short handle)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.iConnected = iConnect;
        this.hndl = handle;

    }
    //Form Load Event
    private void frmMacroVars_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (iConnected)
            lblConnected.Text = "You ARE connected";
        else
            lblConnected.Text = "You are NOT connected";
    }

    //Back Button
    private void cmdBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Close this form and return to main form
        this.Close();
    }

    private void tmrGetMacros_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ODBM odb = new ODBM();
        short odbmSize = 10;            //This value will always be 10. It is the size of the struct
        short retCode = -1;             //The return value of our FOCAS 2 Calls


        ODBAXIS  odba = new ODBAXIS(); //Added for reading the X axis
        short retCodee = -1;
       // int outcome = 0;        // interger needed for converting short to string
       // int test1 = 10;
        //int test2 = 10;


        //Only get the values if we are connected
        if (iConnected)
        {
            try
            {
                //Get the contents of macro variable 500 and put in ODBM struct
                //This requires our handle to the control
                retCode = cnc_rdmacro(hndl, 500, odbmSize, ref odb);
```

This part of the code works where I can receive the info from rdmacro correctly.

```
                if (retCode == 0)
                    txtMac500.Text = InsertDecimal(Convert.ToInt32(odb.mcr_val), Convert.ToInt16(odb.dec_val));
```

This part of the code produces an error. (hndl, 1,1, ref odba) is not the right format. not sure what is.

```
                retCodee = cnc_absolute(hndl, 1,1, ref odba);


                    textBox1.Text = retCodee.ToString(); 

            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }


    //Inserts a decimal place in an integer and returns the string of it
    //This is necessary because we do not get the actual macro variable value back, only the digits and a value that
    //specifies where the decimal place is, so the number must be created manually
    public string InsertDecimal(int value, short decSpot)
    {
        //This takes in an integer 32 and a sport for a decimal and returns a string of an offset value. The decimal
        //point here is represented by a SHORT

        string strValue = value.ToString();

        if (decSpot != -1)
            strValue = (value / Math.Pow(10, decSpot)).ToString();
        else
            strValue = value.ToString();

        return strValue;
    }

    //Update Macro Variable 110 with contents of Textbox
    private void cmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newMacVar = txtWrite110.Text;
        short decIndex = 0;
        int numVal = 0;
        short structLen = 10;       //It is always 10 in length
        short macNum = 110;         //We are writing to mac var 110

        if (!iConnected)
            MessageBox.Show("You are not connected to the control.", "Not Connected");
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtWrite110.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    decIndex = (short)newMacVar.IndexOf('.');

                    if (decIndex <= 0)
                        decIndex = 0;
                    else
                        newMacVar = newMacVar.Remove(decIndex, 1);

                    numVal = Convert.ToInt32(newMacVar);

                    //Write our textbox input to macro variable 110
                    cnc_wrmacro(hndl, macNum, structLen, numVal, decIndex);
                    txtWrite110.Text = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Type a number into the Write 'Macro Variable textbox'", "No Input");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error. Check your input. Error: " + ex.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
    }

    private void txtMac110_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}

}
```

Comment: Not enough information on how you request the information for axis1 to tell you how to display it.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy I believe `ODBAXIS.type == 1`

Comment: Here is the entire program. I have an error on line 130. I'm trying to figure out how to correct display the info from the DLL file. I,m not sure of the correct formatting.

Comment: What error does it produce? It is a compiler error or a run time error? If it is a exception please include the full text of the exception as a edit to the question. Also why are you doing `catch (Exception ex) { }`?

Comment: Here is what I'm getting for errors:

Comment: Here is what I'm getting for errors. Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'SampleFOCAS2Projtest1.frmMacroVars.cnc_absolute(short, short, short, SampleFOCAS2Projtest1.frmMacroVars.ODBAXIS)' has some invalid arguments.
And  Error 2 Argument 4 should not be passed with the 'ref' keyword.       These know why the errors are coming up but in this case I do not know how to resolve them. If I remove the catch (Exception ex) I get the following error. Error 1 Expected catch or finally.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a bit old, but seems unanswered.  Maybe this will help someone in the future:

I do this in VB like this:

```
    Dim AxData As New ODBAXIS

    Dim DataLen As Short
    DataLen = 4 + 4 * MAX_AXIS


    LastError = cnc_absolute(Hndl, -1, DataLen, AxData)
```

Argument 3 is the length of the data that will be retrieved.  "1" is not a valid length.
Also you are using "1" where I am using "-1" in my case I reading all axis data at once.  If you only want to read the 1st axis's data then use "1" as you have done.